# Why I have already added a .dll to unity, but still can't use it/

Tags: unity-game-engine

I added System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll to unity's plugins folder.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9Wl2.png)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qslVe.png)

And I found it appear in the reference of 'assembly-csharp'.

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbTPY.png)

But I still can't "using" it.

[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymnhR.png) [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N97Kl.png)

How do I use it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no namespace named `System.Data.DataSetExtensions`, the assembly contains extension methods, you just need call them with data objects.

An example:

```
DataTable dt;
foreach(var row in dt.AsEnumerable())
    ....
```